# VBA code for subtraction of subsequent numbers in a list from the first value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a list of numbers.  I want to use the first number in the list as a starting value and subtract the subsequent numbers from it, using VBA.

I have made several unsuccessful attempts:

```
Function less(rng As Range)
    X = 0

    For Each cell In rng
    X = X - cell.Value

    Next

    less = X

End Function
```

It results subtraction of all of the values, including the first.  For example, for the sequence 5,7,3,6 my code will give -21. But I expect -11.

Other code I tried is:

```
Function less(rng As Range)
    X = 0

    For Each cell In rng
    X = X + cell.Value
    X = X - cell.Value

    Next

    less = X

End Function
```

It just overrides each value and results as 0.

How can I make the first value in the list the starting value, and then do the subtractions of the subsequent values from it?

I'm not concerned here about the sign of any of the values, only the logical sequence of starting with the first value and subtracting the subsequent values from it.

Note: I am new to VBA and this is my first coding.

Comment: (1) Your code appears to be doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  What’s the problem? (2) Is the entire question about how to skip the first cell in the range?  If so, you should say so more clearly. (3) You say you’re new to VBA.  Are you new to programming in general?  How would you solve your problem(s) (whatever they are) in any programming language you know well? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Can I ask you to clarify what result you expect to have if the range consists of these values: -5, 7, -3, 6? Btw, you do know from elementary arithmetics that subtracting a negative value is the same as adding the same positive value, so x - -1 = x + 1 , don't you?

Comment: As Scott said i edited my question, i just need solution for skipping first value in range.

Comment: For Tom, I do know it well. For given value results will be -21 and my code will give same. But for range 5,7,3,6 also my code will give -21. But i expect -11

Comment: Why did you remove the sample code from your question? Do you want to make it harder for us to understand you?

Comment: @DeepakAggarwal, I clarified your question based on all of your comments.  Let's see if we can get this reopened, which will allow additional solutions.  It may take a little time for voting to reopen the question and for any other solutions to be posted, so keep checking back for maybe a few days.  But at some point, consider accepting an answer if it (best) solves the problem for you (click the checkmark next to it).  That indicates that the problem has been solved and helps other users by indicating there is a proven solution here.  It also awards a little rep to both of you for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Edit (after comments by fixer1234)

Interpreting your question as "skip the first value from the subtraction but include it as a starting value" can be achieved with following function:

```
Function less(rng As Range)
    Dim x, i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng
      If cell.Address = rng.Cells(1, 1).Address Then
        x = cell.Value
      Else
        x = x - cell.Value
      End If
    Next

    less = x
End Function
```

This will also be in accordance with your comment where you said that a range 5, 7, 3, 6 should yield -11

Comment: 5 - 7 - 3 - 6 = -11.  -5 -7 --3 - 6 = -15.  If you're getting -16 and -10, respectively, something is wrong.

Comment: @fixer OP asked: *Any solution where I can skip first cell value in range*, ergo a) skip 5 then - 7 - 3 - 6 = -16 and b) skip -5, then -7 --3 - 6 = -10

Comment: See OP's comment on the question.  By skipping the first item, I think they meant including the first item in the arithmetic as a starting point and subtracting the other items from it rather than subtracting the first item, also, from a starting value of zero.  That's what the OP's code did and what they're trying to fix.  I had already voted to close the question as unclear.  Valiant effort here, and if the OP clarifies things, you may turn out to be right, or can salvage the effort.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 You are right, reinterpreting the question as you said, is most likely correct.

Comment: Dear fixer you are correct "See OP's comment on the question. By skipping the first item, I think they meant including the first item in the arithmetic as a starting point and subtracting the other items from it rather than subtracting the first item, also, from a starting value of zero. "